# Add new child with lxml.etree

Tags: python, xml

this is my xml, i want to append to it some tags, i can write first subelement, but can't write child in this new subelement.
Subelement that i created is called 'movie', i need to create another tag inside that tag

```xml
    <titlovi>
      <login>
        <token></token>
        <userid></userid>
      </login>
      <boris>
        <movies>
          <movie title="Avengers: Endgame"/>
        </movies>
        <tv_shows/>
      </boris>
    </titlovi>
```

Code:

```py
    parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
    titlovi = etree.parse('titlovi.xml', parser).getroot()
    b = etree.SubElement(titlovi[1][0], 'movie').set('title', title)
    c = etree.SubElement(b, 'imdb_id').text = imdb_id
    with open('titlovi.xml', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(etree.tostring(titlovi, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you try your code as above?

Comment: @SimonCrane i get error on line `c = etree.Subelement(b, 'imdb_id').text = imdb_id` and error is `typeerror: argument '_parent' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got NoneType)`

Comment: Then it looks like `etree.SubElement` creates an element but doesn't return anything

Comment: @SimonCrane so 'b' variable is not created correctly? When i do `print(type(b))` i get class NoneType

Comment: I was wrong.  `etree.SubElement` returns an `Element` instance, which you then call `set` on, and the call to `set` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the creation of subelements from the setting of their attributes:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
titlovi = etree.parse('titlovi.xml', parser).getroot()
b = etree.SubElement(titlovi[1][0], 'movie')
b.set('title', title)
c = etree.SubElement(b, 'imdb_id')
c.text = imdb_id
with open('titlovi.xml', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(etree.tostring(titlovi, pretty_print=True))
```